# On Win7 GetOpenFileName function ignores the lpstrInitialDir arguament

Tags: windows-7

I'm using `GetOpenFileName` and setting the `lpstrInitialDir` member of the `OPENFILENAME` struct to the directory I want as the initial directory. However on Win7 my app seems to remember what directory the user last opened and it ignores the `lpstrInitialDir` settings and goes to the last directory.

[Apparently this is by design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646839(VS.85).aspx)

> lpstrInitialDir
>   LPCTSTR
>   The initial directory.
>   The algorithm for selecting the initial directory varies on different platforms.
>
> Windows 7:
>
> 1.If lpstrInitialDir has the same value as was passed the first time the
>   application used an Open or Save As
>   dialog box, the path most recently
>   selected by the user is used as the
>   initial directory.
>   2.Otherwise, if lpstrFile contains a path, that path is the initial
>   directory.
>   3.Otherwise, if lpstrInitialDir is not NULL, it specifies the initial
>   directory.

Does anyone know how to stop this happening?

I want the directory I specify to be the initial directory regardless of what the file the user last opened i.e. I want condition 3 above to apply. I did the obvious and had a search through the registry but I couldn't find anything related to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if you set `lpstrFile` to the required initial directory path (i.e. `lpstrInitialDir`). If you are using `lpstrFile` to specify filename, then you may need to prepend initial directory path to the filename.

Comment: Thanks, that was the suggestion I needed. If I set lpstrFile to a full path then the OpenFile dialog does open at the directory specified in lpstrFile, and it works with a wildcard like C:\path\\*.xml.

Comment: This doesnt work for me, I get "'error 12290.' failed to open.

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is old but I recently had this problem and I found a solution for it.
GetOpenFileName() saves the last used path in the registry. The path is:
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\

There are two keys, I am not sure which actually is used and under what circumstances but I delete my application's entry from both of them. The two keys are:
"LastVisitedPidlMRU" and "LastVisitedPidlMRULegacy".

The application names are saved as RegBinary values with a 16 bit character encoding (this is the reason why it would not show up in a registry search...).
I came up with the following function to delete the registry entries forcing Windows to believe that GetOpenFileName() has never before been called by my application:

```
void clear_path_in_registry ()
{
  char keypath[PATH_MAX];
  char *keys[] = { "LastVisitedPidlMRU", "LastVisitedPidlMRULegacy" };
#define NO_OF_KEYS (sizeof(keys)/sizeof(*keys))
  int keynr;
  HKEY hkey;
  int res;
  char val_data[BUFLEN];
  DWORD val_len, data_len;
  int i;
  char val_name[VALUELEN];
  char progname[PATH_MAX];
  char *p, *q;
  char exename[PATH_MAX];
  int index;
  int *pi , *pj;

  do_debug (1, "clear_path_in_registry()\n");

  GetModuleFileName (NULL, progname, sizeof(progname));
  p = strrchr (progname, '\\');
  if (p)
    p ++;
  strncpy (exename, p, sizeof(exename)-1);
  keynr = 0;
  do
  {
    snprintf (keypath, sizeof(keypath),
     "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\ComDlg32\\%s",
     keys[keynr]);

    res = RegOpenKeyEx (HKEY_CURRENT_USER,keypath,0,KEY_ALL_ACCESS,&hkey);
    if (res == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
      i = 0;
      val_len = sizeof (val_name);
      data_len = sizeof (val_data);
      while (RegEnumValue(
              hkey,i,val_name,&val_len,NULL,NULL,(BYTE *)val_data,&data_len)
        == ERROR_SUCCESS)
      {
        if (stricmp(val_name, "MRUListEx"))
        {
          /* is not the "MRUListEx" value -> extract program name
           *
           * for some (unknown) reason the program names are not stored as
           * RegSZ but rather as RegBinary values. They are encoded in some
           * dual-byte encoding. In my experiments the high bytes are
           * always 0x00; so the transcoding is simple, just skip the high
           * bytes. Probably there is a WIN32 API call for this but I did
           * dig into that for now ...
           */
          p = progname;
          q = val_data;
          while (*q)
          {
            *p++ = *q++;
            q ++;
          }
          *p = '\0';
          /* the index in the MRUList is the value name */
          index = atoi (val_name);
          if (stricmp (progname, exename) == 0)
          {
            /* found the value with current executable name -> delete it */
            res = RegDeleteValue (hkey, val_name);
            if (res == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
              /* delete the entry from the MRUList
               *
               * The MRUListEx value is a of the type RegBinary as well.
               * The data structure is fairly simple: just 4-byte integers
               * one after the other; -1 marks the end of the list
               */
              data_len = sizeof (val_data);
              res = RegQueryValueEx (hkey, "MRUListEx", NULL, NULL,
                                               (BYTE*)val_data, &data_len);
              if (res == ERROR_SUCCESS)
              {
                pi = (int *)val_data;
                pj = (int *)val_data;
                while (*pj != -1)
                {
                  if (*pj == index)
                  {
                    pj ++;
                    data_len -= sizeof(int);
                  }
                  *pi++ = *pj++;
                }
                *pi = *pj;
                res = RegSetValueEx (hkey, "MRUListEx", 0, REG_BINARY,
                                              (BYTE *)val_data, data_len);
                if (res != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                {
                  do_debug (1,"ERROR writing registry value 'MRUListEx'\n");
                }
              } else
              {
                do_debug (1, "ERROR reading registry value 'MRUListEx'\n");
              }
            } else
            {
              do_debug (1,"ERROR deleting registry value '%s'\n",val_name);
            }
          }
        }
        val_len = sizeof (val_name);
        data_len = sizeof (val_data);
        i ++;
      } /* iterate through registry values */
    }
    res = RegCloseKey (hkey);
    if (res != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
      do_debug (1, "Error closing registry key '%s'\n", keys[keynr]);
    }
    keynr ++;
  } while (keynr < NO_OF_KEYS);
}
```

Just call this function before you call GetOpenFileName() and you're fine.

I tested with Windows 10, Version 19042.1052, 64bit.

Johannes